# Customise the number format in Apache superset

Tags: d3.js, number-formatting, apache-superset

I am trying to do some customization in the apache superset. I want to show the number in superset chart in the Indian format. For eg.
1

10

100

1,000

10,000

1,00,000

10,00,000

1,00,00,000

10,00,00,000

In the number format dropdown when I am exploring chart there is no option to show the data like this. I have done set up a dev version of superset on my machine and found that it is using a package superset-ui-number-format. Now I don't know how to proceed with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can edit the code for your Superset instance/deployment, there is a way to accomplish this. This assumes you've pulled your code from GitHub, and thus have a `superset-frontend` folder. If so, then open `superset-frontend/src/setup/setupFormatters.js` and do the following:

1. At the top, alongside `createDurationFormatter` make sure to import `createD3NumberFormatter` from `@superset-ui/number-format`
2. Alongside all the `registerValue` entries following `getNumberFormatterRegistry()`, add one more that looks like so:

```
.registerValue(
  'CURRENCY_INDIA',
  createD3NumberFormatter({
    locale: {
      decimal: '.',
      thousands: ',',
      grouping: [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
      currency: ['₹', ''],
    },
    formatString: '$,.2f',
  }),
)
```

Then, when you're editing a chart in the Explore view, you can **type** `CURRENCY_INDIA` as your formatter, and it should work!

[image: Indian currency formatter]

Optionally, if you're maintaining a fork of `superset-ui` you can add this as an option included in the Explore viz controls. To do that, you would add it in `superset-ui_preset/packages/superset-ui-chart-controls/src/shared-controls/index.tsx` as one of the exported `D3_FORMAT_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Any plan to raise pull request to the master branch?

Comment: I hadn't planned to open a PR for this @Adi, as I haven't heard of any other demand for it, and I feared that if I added a formatter for one currency, we probably *should* do it for all the other major currencies... and add some configuration flags for which ones to enable. It just felt like a slippery slope. 

If you'd like to open a PR, go for it! Or if you're not an engineer and just need it in there, let me know and I can do it.