# Cant create a number format in Docker using Apache Superset

Tags: docker, number-formatting, apache-superset

I am trying to create a BRL number format (R$123,345,789.22) for my big number charts but i don't know how to do that... I looked at this solution here: [Customise the number format in Apache superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319902/customise-the-number-format-in-apache-superset) but I can't make it work. I think it is because the superset is installed locally via docker containers so it just downloads the images and it doesn't matter if I change my local superset files it doesn't change anything in the app (don't know much about docker btw). here is the docker-compose file to build superset

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:${TAG:-latest-dev}
x-superset-depends-on: &superset-depends-on
  - db
  - redis
x-superset-volumes: &superset-volumes
  # /app/pythonpath_docker will be appended to the PYTHONPATH in the final container
  - ./docker:/app/docker
  - superset_home:/app/superset_home

version: "3.7"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: superset_cache
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  db:
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: superset_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db_home:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  superset:
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_app
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app-gunicorn"]
    user: "root"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8088:8088
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-init:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_init
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-init.sh"]
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: "root"
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-worker:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_worker
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "worker"]
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: "root"
    volumes: *superset-volumes

  superset-worker-beat:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset_worker_beat
    command: ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "beat"]
    env_file: docker/.env-non-dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    user: "root"
    volumes: *superset-volumes

volumes:
  superset_home:
    external: false
  db_home:
    external: false
  redis:
    external: false
```

the modified file as in [Customise the number format in Apache superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319902/customise-the-number-format-in-apache-superset) :

```
import {
  createDurationFormatter,

  createD3NumberFormatter,

  getNumberFormatter,
  getNumberFormatterRegistry,
  NumberFormats,
  getTimeFormatterRegistry,
  smartDateFormatter,
  smartDateVerboseFormatter,
} from '@superset-ui/core';



export default function setupFormatters() {
  getNumberFormatterRegistry()
    // Add shims for format strings that are deprecated or common typos.
    // Temporary solution until performing a db migration to fix this.
    .registerValue(',0', getNumberFormatter(',.4~f'))
    .registerValue('null', getNumberFormatter(',.4~f'))
    .registerValue('%', getNumberFormatter('.0%'))
    .registerValue('.', getNumberFormatter('.4~f'))
    .registerValue(',f', getNumberFormatter(',d'))
    .registerValue(',r', getNumberFormatter(',.4f'))
    .registerValue('0f', getNumberFormatter(',d'))
    .registerValue(',#', getNumberFormatter(',.4~f'))
    .registerValue('$,f', getNumberFormatter('$,d'))
    .registerValue('0%', getNumberFormatter('.0%'))
    .registerValue('f', getNumberFormatter(',d'))
    .registerValue(',.', getNumberFormatter(',.4~f'))
    .registerValue('.1%f', getNumberFormatter('.1%'))
    .registerValue('1%', getNumberFormatter('.0%'))
    .registerValue('3%', getNumberFormatter('.0%'))
    .registerValue(',%', getNumberFormatter(',.0%'))
    .registerValue('.r', getNumberFormatter('.4~f'))
    .registerValue('$,.0', getNumberFormatter('$,d'))
    .registerValue('$,.1', getNumberFormatter('$,.1~f'))
    .registerValue(',0s', getNumberFormatter(',.4~f'))
    .registerValue('%%%', getNumberFormatter('.0%'))
    .registerValue(',0f', getNumberFormatter(',d'))
    .registerValue('+,%', getNumberFormatter('+,.0%'))
    .registerValue('$f', getNumberFormatter('$,d'))
    .registerValue('+,', getNumberFormatter(NumberFormats.INTEGER_SIGNED))
    .registerValue(',2f', getNumberFormatter(',.4~f'))
    .registerValue(',g', getNumberFormatter(',.4~f'))
    .registerValue('int', getNumberFormatter(NumberFormats.INTEGER))
    .registerValue('.0%f', getNumberFormatter('.1%'))
    .registerValue('$,0', getNumberFormatter('$,.4f'))
    .registerValue('$,0f', getNumberFormatter('$,.4f'))
    .registerValue('$,.f', getNumberFormatter('$,.4f'))
    .registerValue('DURATION', createDurationFormatter())
    .registerValue(
      'DURATION_SUB',
      createDurationFormatter({ formatSubMilliseconds: true }),
    );


    .registerValue(
      'CURRENCY_BRAZIL',
      createD3NumberFormatter({
        locale: {
          decimal: ',',
          thousands: '.',
          currency: ['R$', ''],
        },
        formatString: '$,.2f',
      }),
    )

  getTimeFormatterRegistry()
    .registerValue('smart_date', smartDateFormatter)
    .registerValue('smart_date_verbose', smartDateVerboseFormatter)
    .setDefaultKey('smart_date');
}
```

so my question is: How can i create a custom number format on docker superset?

I have got this answer from a fellow gentleman made-of-imposter-syndr :
" From what I can see, you are using docker-compose-non-dev.yml as your compose file, which uses pre-built frontend assets, which is why you are not able to see the changes you make.

Try running docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up or simply, docker-compose up (If a file with the name docker-compose.yml file exists, docker-compose up automatically picks that up)"

however, I tried running "docker-compose up" to run superset but now whenever I go to localhost:8088 it shows a weird blank screen:

[blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE5E7.png)

so I cant run superset using docker-compose.yml, it only runs with docker-compose-non-dev.yml but as mentioned above apparently I can't change the code that way.

this is the link of the docker-compose up output logs on my terminal:

https://pastebin.com/iyFBbWdM

can someone help me solve this blank screen?

Comment: Note: my OS is ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hi, I'm having just the same problem as you, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are using `docker-compose-non-dev.yml` as your compose file, which uses pre-built frontend assets, which is why you are not able to see the changes you make.

Try running `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` or simply, `docker-compose up` (If a file with the name `docker-compose.yml` file exists, `docker-compose up` automatically picks that up)

More information about that [here](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose#3-launch-superset-through-docker-compose), in superset documentation

If you are interested in learning more about docker in general, [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-docker-handbook/) was quite useful for me

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question! I tried running docker-compose up but superset doesn't start properly, I edited the main question with more information about this problem, can you help me out?

Comment: Are you getting webpack progress percentage. I can't see it in the pastebin ? It could simply be that your frontend is being built, it takes some time for `docker-compose up`  to run, because the frontend assets have to be built