# Apache Superset - Custom X/Y axis Number Format for Charts

Tags: apache-superset

I have a unique challenge that for graphing in Superset.

I am trying to graph credit ratings across different subsets in Superset. In our database, Credit Ratings are represented numerically (1-21). Each number corresponds to a agency rating (e.g. 1 = AAA, 2 = AA+, 3 = AA, 4 = AA-, ...).

If I graph the average Rating, for example, I would take the average of the 21Notch.

[image: Average 21 Notch Rating]

What I want to do is have the *values* of the Y-axis correspond to the 21-point notch. But the *labels* should reflect the rating (e.g. 8 = BBB+).

So the Y-axis would range from AAA - CCC.

After a bit of research, I think that the best way to do this would be to create a custom number format. I would create a custom number format that would relabel the 21Notch based on a mapping table.

I got the idea after reading the below question.
[Customise the number format in Apache superset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319902/customise-the-number-format-in-apache-superset)

My questions are two-fold:

1. Would creating a custom number format using a mapping table work?
2. Is this the best way to approach this problem or is there a simpler way to achieve the same result?